# I am new to Angular. How do I have to do login page a theme and all other pages with a different theme

Tags: angular

*Login page* with a theme1*emphasized text*
*all other pages* with *theme2*

Comment: What do you mean by theming? angular material themes or some custom approach?

Comment: for example, in home page, there are some pages login page, contact, etc. when user is successfully logged in, there are some pages and all those are worked with side bar and top menu components. What I want it look like using two Master pages one to anonymous user and one for logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Html in layout

```
<app-header></app-header>
  <app-menu></app-menu>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Router should like below

```
    routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'Dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
      { path: 'Users', component: UsersComponent}
    ]}
  },
  {
    path: 'Login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }
];
```